# ubuntu packages hold command

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-kernel, apt, upgrade

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.03 - server and I would like to
hold upgrades for specific ubuntu packages,
it means that apt update & upgrade commands would not affect the specific packages that I would like to preserve.
I have used those commands for maintaining the desired packages - Kernel-related packages.

```
apt-mark hold $(uname -r)
apt-mark hold linux-image-generic-hwe-20.04
apt-mark hold linux-headers-generic-hwe-20.04
```

[image: commands & kernel version]

apt upgrade attempt ended with ignoring the hold that I made:

[image: apt upgrade]

tried using aptitude also did not work.
[image]

[image]

Is there another way from blocking a package from being upgraded from the "apt upgrade command?

Comment: Please, [don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086). Consider replacing the images with text. It's difficult to see what the text in the pictures says on a small screen.

Answer (score 0):

Found out that using an apt-cache preferences file -  /etc/apt/preferences solves the issue.
Create the file with the desired package name, then use "apt update" for having it applied

```
user@user:/etc/apt$ cat preferences
Package: linux-image-*
Pin: release *
Pin-Priority: -1

Package: linux-headers-*
Pin: release *
Pin-Priority: -1
```

Comment: Again, [please don’t post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086). Pin preferences apply immediately, you don’t need to `apt update`.